# Why isn't my Q promise working?

Tags: node.js, q, node-mysql

I'm new to promises and Q, and I'm trying to convert a route that uses `query` in `node-mysql`. Here are excerpts from my code:

```
var Q = require('q');
// connection defined elsewhere

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var query = Q.denodeify(connection.query);
    var promise = query("-- query ommitted --", [req.user.id]);
    promise.then(console.log, console.error);
});
```

I'm trying to convert this from an existing set up that doesn't use promises, so I know the connection is set up properly and the query is valid. Whenever I try to request this route, I get the same message in stderr:

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectionConfig' of undefined]
```

I don't know where it's coming from so I'm not sure how to find the full stacktrace. I also tried an alternate version of this code where I had my own function instead of `console.log` and `console.error`, but this function was never called and the same error appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

You're probably losing the lexical scope to `connection` when you `denodeify` the query method.

Looking at the [Q documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node) it says this can be an issue:

> If you are working with methods, instead of simple functions, you can easily run in to the usual problems where passing a method to another function—like Q.nfcall—"un-binds" the method from its owner.

To fix this try using `Q.nbind` instead:

```
var query = Q.nbind(connection.query, connection);
var promise = query("-- query ommitted --", [req.user.id]);
promise.then(console.log, console.error);
```

---

Original answer:

Looking at the node-mysql source, the only place `connectionConfig` is accessed is in [Pool.js](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/a341518c87ef737c00e42dc5f5cfb10b864374ea/lib/Pool.js). So my guess would be that you've got an issue with how the pool is being configured.

Comment: Like I said, I'm converting this code from existing non-promised code. This code used the pool just fine. Additionally, I have other routes that still use the old code, which uses the same pool without issue.

Comment: This helped me solve my problem, using Promise.  `var query = Promise.denodeify(connection.query.bind(connection))` -- Its the same idea of binding the connection object to the function.